# Is there any Atom plugin for helping to write HTML files?

Tags: atom-editor

I want keystroke bindings and toolbar controls for HTML tags. For example, I want to change a text to hyperlink, I can press Ctrl+L, or click on some toolbar button to add the link. Is there any package for that? Much like what we can find in different blogging websites like blogger.com

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by @Ganzorig autocomplete-html will do the job